# What happens to the Partisans after this event?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

The Partisans are Saw Gerrera's extremist rebel cell that operated on Jedha around the time of *Rogue One*. After Jedha City is

> blown up and the shockwave destroys the Partisans' base,

most of the Partisans escape. What do they do after this? Do they join the larger Rebel Alliance or do something else?

Comment: They are all dead. They may have escaped the facility, but not the explosion. Unless we're not shown them flying away in spaceships.

Comment: I checked the best sources I could (plus the movie). They seem to have survived. And also, there were some other Partisans throughout the galaxy, so they couldn't have all died.

Comment: Some (probably) survived, many died. Beyond that there's no further mention of Saw's men.

Comment: They're no good without Saw Gerrera

Answer (score 3):

We don't know ***yet***

There is a new canon novel releasing this summer called "**Inferno Squad**" that deals specifically with Imperial Forces hunting down the remaining Partisans

> After the humiliating theft of the Death Star plans and the resulting
>   destruction of the battle station, the Empire is on the defensive. In
>   response to this stunning defeat, the Imperial Navy has authorized the
>   formation of an elite team of soldiers, known as Inferno Squad. Their
>   mission: infiltrate and eliminate the remnants of Saw Gerrera’s
>   Partisans.

http://www.starwars.com/news/exclusive-new-novel-inferno-squad

Answer (score 0):

They all escape from Jeddha except Saw Gerrera.
There is a book coming out soon that tells the story about them.
An Imperial elite squadron called 'Inferno Squadron' tries to kill them but so far the evidence points towards Inferno Squadron not completing their mission.

Most of the Partisans survive in the end.

Comment: Can you provide sources where you got this information from? This answer is looking specifically for canon material, can you provide evidence your information is canon?

Comment: Could you please provide a reference to the book comping out (a title would be sufficient, or a link to the news article on the book if title is not available).